# Azure VM: Single disk (filesystem) greater than 1023 GB?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm using Azure Virtual Machines, specifically Linux.  I went to add a blank disk ("attach...blank disk" in the portal) and discovered that Azure only allows a maximum size of 1023GB for disks.  The portal won't allow you to specify a size beyond 1023GB.

What I'm looking for is a 4TB filesystem.  The disks present themselves as /dev/xd?.  I'm wondering if I could take four 1TB disks and stripe them (RAID 0) in the OS?  If they're SAN disks then I'm not concerned about the redundancy since presumably they're already protected.  I admit it sounds kind of hokey.

Is there another option to get bigger disks in Azure?

To be clear, I want persistent storage, not the ephemeral /mnt/storage.

Comment: This probably belongs on serverfault

Comment: I see your point, Luke, though Azure actually points to StackOverflow for questions (which of course doesn't mean it's the right place).

Comment: There's 2 types of azure questions you could ask, how do I code something to work with azure or how do I configure something in azure. The former belongs on this site and the latter belongs on ServerFault. As a general rule of thumb if no code will be written as a result of the answer to this question, it doesn't belong on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You need 4 disks in Raid0 to get 4TB of data. You can follow the guide below; just make sure to change parameters accordingly because the guide uses 3 disks only.

**Configure Software RAID on Linux**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-configure-raid/

Regarding redundancy, no matter what kind of storage you configured in Azure, the worst you can get is 3 mirrors for each disk so just go for full performance.

**Azure Storage Replication**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-redundancy/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you may use Storage Spaces

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dfurman/archive/2014/04/27/using-storage-spaces-on-an-azure-vm-cluster-for-sql-server-storage.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831739.aspx